# How can I make background-size:cover work in IE10 without making attachment fixed?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, w3c

My code:

```
html
{
background-image:url('img.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center top;
background-size:cover;
}
```

This works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome, but on IE the image doesn't get stretched at all. It will work if I set background-attachment to "fixed" but that isn't what I want.

Every website I've looked at claims that these proprties are perfectly implement in IE, but they clearly aren't.

Answer (score 5):

### Troubleshoot CSS Background Size Cover

It's a bit hard to troubleshoot without seeing additional code or the website, but here are some things you can try.

1. Try adding background-attachment:scroll; instead of leaving it blank
2. Is your doctype correct, or does it have typos?
3. Are there other scripts or styles on the HTML tag that may be interfering/overwriting the background style?
4. Hit F12 to open Developer Tools, and click on the HTML tag to see what styles are listed. Toggling the CSS styles on an off for key elements on your site can help you troubleshoot the problem.
   If you are in IE Developer Tools, check to see if "Document Mode" and/or "Browser Mode" are set to an older browser. (IE6, IE7 and IE8 don't recognize background-size:cover, and will show the background in its original size - [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-image) support table.)
5. Is your background only filling the browser window, and not expanding to cover the document page/scrollable areas? Try adding height:100%, width:100%, margin:0 and padding:0 to your HTML and BODY tags. (The *default* HTML and BODY tags have different styles. The HTML size is controlled by the browser window, while the BODY will wrap around the contents, regardless if the contents are less than the browser window, or expands past it.) Also try switching the background to the BODY, or the wrapper tag.
6. To help troubleshoot, make a basic test page with the HTML, BODY and wrapper tag only (if you use a wrapper), and see if you can get the background to function properly. This will help you narrow down the bug. Your wrapper may need a height and width too. Depending on your wireframe (DIV or CSS Table, HTML Table), it may need: min-height:100% and min-width:100%, or height:100% and width:100%.

I created a simple html page with the css you provided, did not include a background-attachment, and used `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the doctype. The background worked well and fully covered the screen as expected in Windows Vista/IE9, Windows 7/IE10 and Windows 8/IE11.

Side Note: [Full background Stack Overflow solution for IE7 and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415191/scale-background-image-to-fit-ie8-window/19422996#19422996)