# Background image fit on screen IE10

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to set the background image in CSS to fit the screen. It's working fine with latest version of Chrome, however, I'm having issue with IE 10.

```
html {
border-top: 10px solid #8A85A5;
background: url("http://www.lifeintempe.com/gfx/photos/2008-11-28-tempe-sunset-56632.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed ;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

}

This is how it's displaying in IE 10. There're so much white space...
Any suggestion on how I can resolve this?

[image]

I also tried adding...Didn't work.

```
min-height:100%;
min-width: 100%;
```

UPDATE:

The above is all I have in my CSS file.  Here's how my `html` looks like:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="ScreenPop.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel ="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="Style/MyStyle.css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `html` to `body` in your css?

Comment: Is Chrome merely stretching your image? Either way, have you tried setting width:100% ?

Comment: @imtherman, yes I have. Same result.

Comment: What `doctype` do you have declared?

Comment: @ne1410s, yes I tried that also, same output.

Comment: @TylerH, `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Can you post more of your code? It's working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/4d6y9twe/1/embedded/result/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/69evLca1/3/ works for me in IE10. Try setting `height: 100%;` and `width: 100%;`. Because `HTML` does not have inherent height (it inherits it from viewport).

Comment: Have you tried hard-coding the image size to a dynamically-grabbed width in javascript? (Not ideal, but it's all I can think of!)

Comment: @TylerH, I have tried using `height: 100%;` and `width: 100%;`

Comment: @imtheman, I posted the code...

Comment: @user1426542 `height` and `width` are different from `min-height` and `min-width`. Trying the latter is not the same as trying the former.

Comment: @TylerH, I tried `height` and `width` after you said "try setting `height:100%`... Still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
html {
border-top: 10px solid #8A85A5;
background-color: #d5d5d5;
background-image: url('http://www.lifeintempe.com/gfx/photos/2008-11-28-tempe-sunset-56632.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
background-size: 100%;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://www.lifeintempe.com/gfx/photos/2008-11-28-tempe-sunset-56632.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://www.lifeintempe.com/gfx/photos/2008-11-28-tempe-sunset-56632.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Use a `wrapper div` like this:

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="http://www.lifeintempe.com/gfx/photos/2008-11-28-tempe-sunset-56632.jpg" alt="">
</div>


#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rj1kx54t/)**

**Update**

After a bit of Googling found this one and yes it worked for me. I have tested it. Hope it works for you.

```
<body> <img src="http://www.lifeintempe.com/gfx/photos/2008-11-28-tempe-sunset-56632.jpg" alt="background image" id="bg" />
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
</form>
</body>


html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
img#bg {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: it's not working for me. This is how it looks like [image](http://s13.postimg.org/3tcc21vlj/notworking.png)

Comment: Have you tried giving CSS to both `body and html`. like this `html,body{..CSShere}`

Comment: Yes, I tried that also. All it does it creates another bar like this underneath: `border-top: 10px solid #8A85A5;`

Comment: As alternate, can you use a `wrapper div`? for all your contents. It will solve the problem. If that's ok with you I can update the answer.

Comment: that's weird. Both of the above solutions worked for me. Its a random guess but try `Clearing History and Cache of IE` and then the both of above solutions.

Comment: Have a look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883280/how-can-i-make-background-sizecover-work-in-ie10-without-making-attachment-fixe)

Comment: I tried every suggestion on that topic. Same output. Could be that my IE 10 is corrupted?

Comment: I have updated the answer with another `code` try that and see the results. It worked for me. If that doesn't work too, then you might consider re installing or updating the IE. [Link for IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318378) and then try all of the above solutions.

Comment: Perfect! That works. Although, I lost this...`border-top: 10px solid #8A85A5;` I tried adding it, but I don't see it. But it resolved my main issue.